# Making a web page 'safari reader' mode compatible?

Tags: safari

I am trying to find some documentation that would indicate on how best to optimise a web page so that it is recognised by Safari's reader mode?

I have found some old pages that suggested it was based on the amount of text, but I have one page with a whole text block, split into multiple sections, but the reader mode icon is not displayed.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at pages that work and those that don't has led me to believe the functionality is based on the type of mark-up in a block.

For that to work it seems to work what the largest block is which has the largest ratio of text elements (`<p>`, `<br/>`, `<ul>`, `img` etc) and text. Anything in a block type element, such a 'div', in that section is then ignored (presumably assuming it is out of context).

There are probably other subtleties, but removing an unnecessary block element from my content section and ensuring it only contained text type markup helped it be selected for the reader.